# React Native: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to change the Header Title to an image, but I can't get it to work. What I have tried is use the LogoTitle class to render an image instead of a title in my Top Tab Navigator, hiding the header works and rendering a title works also:

```js
TopNavigator.navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle:'test'
};
```

And then I tried to change it to an image:

```js
TopNavigator.navigationOptions = () =>{
    headerTitle:<LogoTitle/>
};
```

I use the latest Expo SDK

This is my full code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import PartyScreen from '../screens/PartyScreen';
import EventScreen from '../screens/EventScreen';
import FestivalScreen from '../screens/FestivalScreen';
import ActivityScreen from '../screens/ActivityScreen';
import TestScreen from '../screens/TestScreen';

class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/Header_Logo.png')}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'center', backgroundColor: 'black' }}
        />
        );
    }
}

const PartyStack = createStackNavigator({
    Party: PartyScreen,
});

PartyStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: "Partys",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                'md-calendar'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const EventStack = createStackNavigator({
    Event: EventScreen,
});

EventStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Events',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
            'md-calendar'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const FestivalStack = createStackNavigator({
    Festival: FestivalScreen,
});

FestivalStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Festivals',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
            'md-calendar'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const ActivityStack = createStackNavigator({
    Activity: ActivityScreen,
});

ActivityScreen.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Activiteit',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
            'md-calendar'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const TestStack = createStackNavigator({
    Test: TestScreen,
});

TestScreen.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Test',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
            'md-calendar'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const TopNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    PartyStack,
    EventStack,
    FestivalStack,
    ActivityStack,
    TestStack
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#5B71F9',
      inactiveTintColor: '#888888',
      showIcon: false,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      },
      scrollEnabled : true,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        shadowColor: '#fff',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        height: 47,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#E8E8E8'
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        height: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#5B71F9'
      },
    }, 

},  navigationOptions = {
        header:{visible:false}
});

TopNavigator.navigationOptions = {
     headerTitle:<LogoTitle/>
};

export default TopNavigator;
```

I don't get why it does render Text but images wont, I guess it has to do with the brackets

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    const RouteConfigs = {
      // Your routes
    };

    const StackNavigatorConfig = {
     navigationOptions: {
        header: (navigation) => ({
              title: ( <LogoTitle navigation={navigation} /> )
            })
      },
    };

export default createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, StackNavigatorConfig);
```

Comment: I have replaced it with: 

'TopNavigator.navigationOptions = {
        header: (navigation) => ({
            title: ( <LogoTitle navigation={navigation} /> )
          })
 };'

But that doesn't work.

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Sorry i really don't get it, could you provide me with an example based on my code?

Comment: The thing i was trying to point out is that ... in order to render a component in the title, we don't use this syntax >>
 
`{
    headerTitle:<LogoTitle/>
}`

but we use this >>

    `{
        header: (navigation) => ({
              title: ( <LogoTitle navigation={navigation} /> )
            })
      }`



in the navigationOptions object